# Table doesnt fit in page

Tags: tables

I have the following code for a table

```
    \begin{center}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      \textbf{Recursos} & \textbf{Unidad de Medida} & \textbf{Precio Unitario (Bs/UM)} & \textbf{Cantidad Total Requerida} & \textbf{Monto (Bs)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Fuente}} \\
      \cline{6-8}
      & & & & & \textbf{Recursos Propios} & \textbf{Universidad} & \textbf{Empresa} \\
      \hline
      & & & & & & & \\
      \hline
      & & & & & & & \\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Ejemplo de tabla con el formato deseado.}
    \label{tabla:ejemplo}
  \end{table}
\end{center}
```

However, some of the column texts overlap and the table doesnt fit in all of the page, resulting in this
[image]

I'm trying to make my table look like this (example i made in word)

[image]

how can i fix my code?

Comment: Whatever else you do, never encase a `table` (or, for that matter, `figure`) environment inside a `center` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track by employing a `tabularx` environment, which lets you specify an overall target width (say, `\textwidth`) for the table.

What's still needed is to allow line breaking in all 8 columns, not just the first column. You also need to allow hyphenation of the words in the headers. The following code accomplishes these objectives. Note that all 8 columns are assigned equal width; please let me know if this setting is not appropriate or desirable for your real table -- and which assignment of widths would be more appropriate.

The code also provides a utility macro, called `\mytab`, for typesetting the material in 4 of the header cells.

Finally, do consider omitting all vertical rules -- trust me, they won't be missed -- and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules. There's also no need to **bold-face** the header cells' contents. The result of making these adjustments will be a table that has a much more open and inviting "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' and '\Centering' macros
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
%% define two variants of the 'X' col. type:
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\smash[b]' macro
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}C@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp] % do _not_ encase it in a 'center' env.
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{7}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
    Recursos 
    & \mytab{Unidad de Medida} 
    & \mytab{Precio Unitario (Bs/UM)} 
    & \mytab{Cantidad Total Requerida} 
    & \mytab{Monto (Bs)} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Fuente} \\
    \cmidrule(l){6-8}
    & & & & & Recursos Propios & Universidad & Empresa \\
    \midrule
    abd \dots & def & & & & & & \\
    \addlinespace
    uvw \dots & xyz & & & & & & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Ejemplo de tabla con el formato deseado.}
  \label{tabla:ejemplo}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```